# jQuery mobile - get response of latest pageload

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a website with jQuery mobile and the following problem: In my website is a link with a data-redirectURI attribute that is outside of the data-role="content" area. The value of the data-dash will never be changed because of this. But I want to update the value on each pageload from the jQuery mobile framework. Is there a way to retrieve the latest AJAX response from the pageload/change event?

Comment: share your code and elaborate on _latest AJAX response_.